# failed to install eclipse using oomph on Win10

Tags: installation, java, eclipse

I am trying to install newest eclipse version 2018-12 using oomph installer downloaded from eclipse.org after installing newest jdk 11.0.2 on my Win10 computer. The installer lets me choose installation type. As soon as I click "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" I get an "Internal error: NullPointerException" pop up with the below stack trace as details. Searched and found no solution or even mention of this. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.getImageURI(SetupWizard.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.getLocalBrandingImageURI(SetupWizard.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleProductPage.renderProduct(SimpleProductPage.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.setProductVersion(SimpleVariablePage.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.setProduct(SimpleVariablePage.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleInstallerDialog.productSelected(SimpleInstallerDialog.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleProductPage.productSelected(SimpleProductPage.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleProductPage$ProductList.productSelected(SimpleProductPage.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleProductPage$ProductComposite.mouseUp(SimpleProductPage.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.AbstractSimpleDialog.show(AbstractSimpleDialog.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```